# Disabling the ability to receive my own outgoing multicast datagrams

Tags: network-programming, udp, multicast, rhel6, nic

Is the below code enough to disable the loopback interface from receiving my own outgoing multicast traffic? My udp code appears to still receive packets even when I pull the RJ-45 Ethernet cable from the NIC.

```
char loopch = 0;

if(setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_LOOP, (char *)&loopch, sizeof(loopch)) < 0){
    perror("Setting IP_MULTICAST_LOOP error");
    close(sd);
    return -1;}
```

Comment: Your edited question doesn't make sense. Why should pulling the cable prevent multicast loopback of your own sends? Multicast loopback doesn't have to go through the cable.

Comment: If I am disabling multicast from being looped back to my lo interface with the above code, then my application shouldn't receive any traffic with the cable unplugged. Logical statement? Essentially I am saying the above code does not seem to disable multicast traffic from being looped back to my lo interface.

Answer (score 0):

No. It does a different thing. It enables or prevents you from receiving your own outbound multicasts. See the [*man* page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html).

However your code is wrong. The argument should be an integer.

I'm not aware of anything that controls whether you receive multicasts on the loopback interface.

Comment: Sorry for the non-descriptive question, it had been edited.

Comment: Where can I find that the argument passed should be an integer? The man page says int, but code all over the internet uses char.

Comment: You can find it in, err, the *man* page. I can't account to you for the state of the Internet.